# Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read() with MySql at answer.text = dr(1) or question.text =dr(3) when click get password

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Forgot_Password_form
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("host=localhost;username=root;password=system;database=bike")
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from login where userid='" & useridtxt.Text & "'and question='" & question.Text & "'and answer='" & answertxt.Text & "'"
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If Not dr Is Nothing Then
                dr.Read()
                answer.Text = dr(1)
                dr.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("UserID or answer is incorrect")
        End Try
        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Exit__Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Exit_.Click
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Login_Menu.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub useridtxt_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles useridtxt.LostFocus
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from login where userid='" & useridtxt.Text & "'"
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If Not dr Is Nothing Then
                dr.Read()
                question.Text = dr(3)
                dr.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Code only questions are not clear

Comment: the login and register is ok but the forgot password are always have an error invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read() with MySql

Comment: thats all the codes because it cant fit to the comments

Comment: http://smartprogram.in/vbnet/vb_with_MySQL/5.forgotpassword.aspx the coded are in the website im using vb 2012 and mysql workbench for my database

Comment: It's not a big deal but the `ExecuteReader` method accepts a `CommandBehavior` value as an argument so, if you expect only a single row, you should optimise the operation by passing `SingleRow` as an argument.